# Call a function inside a switch inside a function

Tags: jquery

So, I'm having a function that returns random results and depending on that result, I want to call another function, but it doesn't work right now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#classbutton').click(function () {
        $('#resultclass').text(classX());
 });
});

function subkrieger() {
    var subkriegerNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
        switch (subkriegerNumber) {
            case 1:
                return "Berserkerin";
            case 2:
                return "Duellantin";
            }
}

function classX() {
    var classNumber = Math.floor((Math.random()*2)+1);
        switch (classNumber) {
            case 1:
                return "Kriegerin";
                return subkrieger();
            case 2:
                return "Mystikerin";
        }
}

    <button id="classbutton">Archetyp</button>
    <div id="resultclass" class="results"></div>
```

So, the first function is for getting a sub-fantasyclass for the 2nd function, that randomly returns a fantasy rpg class. I tried to call the 1st function in case 1 of the 2nd function to try it out, but nothing is happening.
What am I doing wrong?

And there is probably a way to do this much more elegantly than having a bunch of switches?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that still shows your problem.

Comment: I added the minimal rest of the code.

Comment: Minimal not maximal amount of code!

Comment: I'm so sorry, I misunderstood. I shortened it.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
return "Krieger";
return subkrieger();                
break;
```

You are returning a string, which ends the execution of that function, so you never get to the `subkrieger()` call.

If you remove the `return "Krieger"` line, that'll let it call. If you want both (like say something like `Krieger Berserkerin`, then you'll want to concatenate (add) them together:

```
return "Krieger " + subkrieger();
```

or with ES6 style:

```
return `Krieger ${subkrieger()}`;
```

Side note: having a `break;` after a `return` is redundant, because it'll never get to the break anyways, so just leave it off and do:

```
case:
    return "Krieger";
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I see my mistake now, but your solution doesn't work. It returns: "Krieger " + subkrieger()

Comment: Sorry about that, typo in my first one example. It shouldn't have had the backticks. I fixed it.